# Stepper motor control via RC receiver

Tags: while-loop, arduino, stepper

I am new to Arduino programming and have spent a couple days getting this far, but cannot seem to figure out why this code is not working.

I am trying to control a stepper motor using a hobby grade remote control RX/TX.

I have an RC receiver sending an analog value from 1000 to 2000 to my Arduino. If that signal is 1000, I would like to make 1000 = -360 degrees on the stepper and 2000 = +360 degrees on the stepper.

I am receiving the correct signals from the receiver and printing them to the serial monitor, but I cant seem to control the stepper motor with this value yet. This motor simply gets stuck in the first while loop and continues to spin in 1 direction.

```cpp
int ch1 = 0;                                // RC Reciever Channel Value
int ch1previous = 0;                        // RC Receiver Channel Previous Value
int PUL=7;                                  //define Pulse pin of stepper driver
int DIR=6;                                  //define Direction pin of stepper driver
int ENA=5;                                  //define Enable Pin of stepper driver

void setup() {
  pinMode (PUL, OUTPUT);                    // Stepper Driver Pulse Pin
  pinMode (DIR, OUTPUT);                    // Stepper Driver Direction Pin
  pinMode (ENA, OUTPUT);                    // Stepper Driver Enable Pin
  pinMode(3, INPUT);                        // RC Reciever Pin Input
  Serial.begin(9600);                       

}

void loop() {

  ch1 = pulseIn(3, HIGH, 50000);                    // Read RC Reciever Channel Value

while ( ch1 > ch1previous) {                        // If CH1 is greater than CH1Previous run the differance
      for ( int i = ch1; i < ch1previous; i++);{    // in steps to maintain the setpoint value in forwared position
      digitalWrite(DIR,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);                       // pulsing stepper motor in forward motion
      digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(50);
      digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(50);
}
  }

 while ( ch1 < ch1previous) {                      // if CH1 is less than CH1Previous run the differance
      for ( int i = ch1; i<ch1previous; i--);{      // in steps to maintain the setpoint value in reverse motion
      digitalWrite(DIR,LOW);
      digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);                       // pulsing stepper motor in reverse motion
      digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(50);
      digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    }
  }


  Serial.print ("Channel 1: ");             // print text to the serial monitor
  Serial.println(ch1);                      // print ch1 value to the serial monitor and end line
  Serial.print("CH1 Previous: ");           // print text to the serial monitor 
  Serial.println(ch1previous);              // print ch1previous value to the serial monitor and end line
  ch1previous = ch1;                        // remember the previous value from ch1

  delay(500);                               // just to clean up the serial monitor
}
```

Comment: Both the while conditions will go on infinitely if they are started even once. As you have put in comments  `If CH1 is greater than CH1Previous run the difference`, these `while` conditions have to be replaced by `if statements`. That is, make them as `if(ch1 > ch1previous)` and `else if(ch1 < ch1previous)` .

Comment: What's the point of `;` after the for loops? Those for loops are do nothing.

Comment: You seem to expect the pulse to be up to 50000 micro seconds. But you are storing it into an `int` which can only store the maximum of 32767. Use `unsigned long` for `ch1`  and `ch1previous`.

Comment: @Sma you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @gre_gor Okay, i will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Can 
`ch1 = pulseIn(3, HIGH, 50000)`
ever be a negative value?  if not, then that could explain this behavior, when you consider this statement:

```
 while ( ch1 > ch1previous) {
```

and `ch1previous` is initialized to zero.

Comment: [`pulseIn`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn) returns an `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

Both the `while` conditions will go on infinitely if they are started even once. As you have put in comments `If CH1 is greater than CH1Previous run the difference`, these while conditions have to be replaced by `if statements`. That is, make them as `if(ch1 > ch1previous)` and `else if(ch1 < ch1previous)`. And for loops' conditions should also be reversed, as per the if condition bounding them.

After these changes, your code will become something like this

```
void loop() {
    ch1 = pulseIn(3, HIGH, 50000);

    if ( ch1 > ch1previous) {
        for ( int i = ch1; i > ch1previous; i--){
            //code
        }
    }

    else if ( ch1 < ch1previous) {
        for ( int i = ch1; i<ch1previous; i++){
            //code
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You! this now behaves much more like I was hoping, however I am now getting a drift on the stepper motor it very slowly moves in the CW direction even though my set point value doesn't change, any ideas?